# KafkaHandler for multiple JSON types in Single Kafka Topic - Process in batch

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

### TL/DR; is it possible to use separate KafkaHandlers for different JSON types in batch mode?

I have a topic I am consuming that contains several different JSON messages.  I am processing the data and inserting into a database so I am processing this in batch and manually doing the Kafka commit once everything has been inserted into the database.

So I have my factory which includes

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
```

and the factory sets

```
factory.setBatchListener(true);
```

For testing I have two POJOs that are TypeA with strings var1 & var2 and TypeB with strings (var3 and var4).  My consumer then has a method which is essentially:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topics}");
public void receive (List<Object> data, Acknowledgement ack) {
  for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    Object d = data.get(i);
    if (d instanceof TypeA) {
      LOGGER.info("We have Type A - '{}' - '{}'", a.getVar1(), a.getVar2());
    }
    if (d instancef TypeB) {
      LOGGER.info("We have Type B - '{}' - '{}'", b.getVar3(), a.getVar4());
    }
  }
  ack.acknowledge();
}
```

This works but I have been attempting to to get this to work using KafkaHandlers for each type instead of using instanceof.

If I remove the line to enable batch processing and move the `KafkaListener` annotation to the class level I can then create separate handlers

```
@KafkaHandler
public void receiveA(@Payload TypeA) {
 LOGGER.info("We have Type A - '{}' - '{}'", a.getVar1(), a.getVar2());
}
@KafkaHandler
public void receiveB(@Payload TypeA) {
  LOGGER.info("We have Type B - '{}' - '{}'", a.getVar3(), a.getVar4());
}
```

This works fine but I loose the batch ability.

If I enable batch mode then it only seems to want a handler for ArrayList and you can't have separate handlers for the different types.

Is there some middle ground here?   Is there any way I could processes the individual records using `KafkaHandler` but have something that fires once all the records have been processed by their handlers (to handle the acknowledgment and database commits) or is there a better way of handling this than in the first code using lots if instance of statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@KafkaHandler` is currently not supported for batch listeners; <strike>please open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues) - we should be able to properly detect the generic list contents type from the generic parameter type.</strike>

You might be able to use a custom `BatchToRecordAdapter` to call the record level listener, and set some flag in the final message in the batch to signal that it is the last.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions-batch

**EDIT**

It doesn't make sense to support `@KafkaHandler` - the batch could contain mixed types.

Comment: See my comment about `BatchToRecordAdapter`.

Comment: After further thought; it doesn't make sense to support `@KafkaHandler` here - the batch could contain mixed types.